# Convergence of Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform, analytic-functions

Suppose that $F: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is analytic when $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$. Assume that it is possible to show that $F$ can be represented as a Laplace transform
$$
F(z) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\rm e}^{ - zt} f(t)\,{\rm d}t,
$$
for $\operatorname{Re}(z)>a$ with some non-negative constant $a$ and $f$ being analytic in a neighbourhood of the positive real line. Does it follow from the analyticity of $F$ for $\operatorname{Re}(z)>0$ that $a=0$?

Comment: I love how you asked thus question 2 years ago and never touched it ever again.

Comment: @RounakSarkar What do you expect from me to do with it?

Comment: If I don't get an answer to one of my questions then I actively seek it by giving bounties and cleverly editing the question to bring to more attention. I made the previous comment because I didn't expected such inactivity in a question from a big user like you.

Comment: @Gary Have you come across an answer to this question?

Comment: @bob No, unfortunately I have not.